# Visual Studio 2010 current row highlight

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm using Productivity Power Tools' Highlight current line feature. However, I'd also like to highlight the current *column* (i.e. have a vertical highlighting bar).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. How could you have a common highlight column when the font is not Fixed.

Comment: Though, to be fair, I suspect most people code using fixed width fonts. ;)

Comment: And I am one of them, but still, I have never seen this functionality implemented in any add-ins. (ReSharper, CodeRush, PowerTools). Am I wrong?

Comment: No, that doesn't mean it's not possible though. =) People do all kinds of crazy stuff. It would probably not be all that useful, but hey.